# lcbjni in Intersystems Cache

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems, intersystems-ensemble

We have Intersystems Cache 2010.2.3.702.0.10761 installed on AIX. When I run an eXtreme - Globals API program I am seeing LCBJNI related errors.

Does the Cache 2010.2.3.702.0.10761 have lcbjni? If so, where can I find. Please help

Answer (score 1):

2010.2 requires an extra step on Unix. You need to Set the environment variable LD_PRELOAD to the path of libjsig.so. Here is [documentation]http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BLXT_intro#BLXT_intro_config

```
find $JAVA_HOME -name libjsig.so -print
setenv LD_PRELOAD /my_jdk_path/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/amd64/libjsig.so
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check for correct GLOBALS_HOME, PATH and CLASSPATH envirroment variables.
check it in [documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20122/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BXJV_intro#BXJV_intro_config_environ)

Comment: That is right. I got it working with the latest windows cache version downloaded. However when I run the same jar file in AIX environment where older version of Cache 2010.2.3.701.0.10761, it can't find the lcbjni even after setting the GLOBALS_HOME.                              I wonder if Globals API works with 2010.2.3 version of Cache. IF it does work, Can you point me to the 2010.2.3 version documentation?

Comment: important to set PATH enviroment to CACHE\BIN. and for 2012.2.3 same documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. Actually the version I was asking for was 2010.2.3. I set the PATH to CACHE\BIN. But still can't fix the issue. And I don't find lcbjni in CACHE\BIN directory. Does it come with the 2010.2.3 version?

Comment: I don't have 2012.2.3 installed, only 2013.1 and 2014.1. but in my cache\bin I have liblcbjni.so